Expose animation BP variables in character BP details panel
I have an Animation Blueprint which has a variable MyVar, is there anyway I can expose it such that it shows up in the Character BP Details Panel?

So far I've had to make a duplicate MyVar in the Character and set it via blueprint:

Which is really inconvenient if I have to set a lot of variables
(I'm open to a c++ solution as well)

Unfortunately, this is not possible without engine changes.
